# Aligning text to right bottom of an image

Tags: css-float, alignment

I'm using the following code to align a caption to the right bottom of an image. The code works well.

I was wondering if it was possible to rewrite it **without specifying the min-width** of the picture container (.picture class). With no width the caption shifts down when resizing the browser window:

```
<div class="picture">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class='captioning'>
        <div class='title'>text</div>
        <div class='caption'>text</div>
    </div>
</div>

.picture {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 1200px;
}
.picture img {
    float: left;
}
.picture .captioning {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}
.picture .captioning .caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.picture .captioning .title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "shifts down"?

Comment: it collapses under the photo

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what behavior you mean

Comment: This behavior: [link](http://i42.tinypic.com/mio4rc.jpg)

Comment: I see now, but I can't recreate the behavior. Perhaps you can create an example on jsFiddle or a similar site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used **display: inline-block** on both the image and the caption, and **white-space: nowrap** on the container:

```
.picture {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.picture img {
    display: inline-block;
}
.picture .captioning {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    white-space: normal;
}
.picture .captioning .caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.picture .captioning .title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```